# How to use Spring cloud config server to serve web-ui configuration as well

Tags: spring, user-interface, spring-cloud-config-server

I have a couple of services (microservices) that have Web applications bound to them. In my services, there is an endpoint to serve UI configuration. That means when someone hits the site, the config endpoint is called and UI gets the required configuration.

By the way, the country code, as well as locale, is passed to this config endpoint which customizes the configuration for that user. (means we have to do some validation as well as filling some place holders in the original configuration).

Having this in mind how I could leverage the usage of Spring Cloud configuration for UI configuration in my case?
If there is a better approach for this purpose let me know.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

what is UI configuration? since you are passing the locale info, I believe  it's more like localization texts!? how different are placeholders can they be sort of compiled and provided as static values?

spring config would be overkill and I don't think it should be used for such a case.

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain it properly. The word locale would be misleading. I don't want to load ui-key translations from config server but some specific configuration like some links located in some pages but these links could be different for different locales. Or feature toggles as configuration. As you could see there would be some logic for providing the right configuration. I was wondering if I could use Spring config server (many things in place already like versioning, git integration and etc.) and somehow add my logic to it with some interceptors or sth like that